# How is the dragon blowing fire in the last episode of Season 7?

Tags: game-of-thrones

If the blue flames that the dead dragon is blowing from its mouth is fire in the last episode of Season 7 ... how is that possible?

The army of the dead get killed by fire. Now the dragon is (un)dead, how is it creating and blowing fire? Fire should kill it no?

Comment: Related: [What does this creature breathe in “The Dragon and the Wolf”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79615/49)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68443/discussion-on-question-by-atm-how-is-the-dragon-blowing-fire-in-got-last-epidose).

Answer (score 5):

**It is a different kind of fire now the dragon is (un)dead.**

> "The way I looked at it was, when the sept burned down, that was green fire, and so then the dragon is going to have some kind of blueish fire,” he said. “It’s certainly still fire — it has the ability to burn the Wall and melt snow. **But it’s going to have a different kind of magical quality to it, because it’s coming from an undead dragon."**
>
> <sub>[Game Of Thrones’ Director Explains That Shocking Ice Dragon Scene](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/game-of-thrones-director-explains-that-shocking-ice-dragon-scene_us_59a5628de4b050afa90ca531)</sub>

> So what the chemical nature of that is and **the chemical nature of fire would actually be different coming from a non-sentient being.** So there’s definitely some thought into that of what that should actually look like. But obviously, an ice dragon is going to have an icy kind of fire but it’s still fire.”
>
> <sub>[‘Game of Thrones’ Finale Director Reveals How Daenerys and Jon Had a Date With Destiny](http://www.indiewire.com/2017/08/game-of-thrones-finale-daenerys-jon-snow-dragon-jeremy-podeswa-hbo-1201870908/2/)</sub>

We do not know at this time what the full extent of those magical properties are, but they must interact in a way that allows the dragon to live.

However I do not see why the blue fire could not still kill the wights or even White Walkers. After all regular dragon fire still kills living humans...

Comment: `However I do not see why the blue fire could not still kill the wights or even White Walkers.` The wights' weakness to fire seems to be magically enhanced. It's not a "normal" response to burning, they seem more flammable than a similar corpse that is not animated. I'd expect the wights to still experience a "normal" response to fire (blue or not), but maybe the _magical flammability_ doesn't apply for the blue fire.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on magic, dragon biology, wight magic and wight biology, none of which is explained, so we don't really know.

I think you are thinking of dragons as having an internal furnace and bellowing out flames.  One possible alternative would be if dragons instead had glands. There are volatile chemicals that react violently when they come into contact with, say, water. There are also "binary" chemicals that are relatively inert, but react violently when joined together.

[YouTube - Potassium in water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jy1DC6Euqj4)

If a dragon had glands and their "fire" was a fluid that was explosively combustible when exposed to oxygen, then it would safely reside in the glands until spewed out by the dragon, so it wouldn't be containing "fire" on the inside.

Using the binary chemical model, if the dragon had two separate glands, and spewed forth each one from a different opening, then they'd only burst into flames as they mixed, after being spit out and away from the dragon.

Or, magic.