# What is the extent of damage that Viserion's blue fire can cause?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In another post on *Game of Thrones*, [it is already discussed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/79629/73351) that Viserion's breath is a sort of fire. And we have already seen that it is a quite powerful fire as it can destroy a mighty wall and later on, it sort of melts the walls of Winterfell.

But in episode 3 of season 8, we also see that in the close battle between Rhaegal (rode by Jon) and Viserion, the blue fire kind of reaches Jon and his dragon with no serious damage as far as I saw. Also in another scene, Jon is hidden behind a few dead bodies and Viserion breathes its blue fire to those bodies which does no harm to Jon. As it is sort of ironic that the "great-wall-melting-fire" can be avoided by using a few dead bodies as a shield,

I am interested to know about the capabilities and limitations of this sort of fire.

Comment: It gives you the ouchies.

Comment: there is no magnitude scale about dragonfire power, so hard to give you an exact answer. Also, when he attack Jon, he is already quite injured, so his power may be lessen

Comment: To all who might be mad at me for the spoilers: I _did_ hide them, but the higher powers removed the spoiler tag by editing my question. Don't know why

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ Hi! There is no need to hide the question behind the spoiler box. Just keep the title spoiler-free. That's why I removed them. Take a look at our [our policy](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1788/27264) on spoiler and [why we don't want to hide the question body behind a yellow box](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/83/27264).

Comment: @AJ Except the contents _do_ show on the tag and search results pages so keeping the first few lines spoiler free should be done. Then as a courtesy you should add spoiler markdown throughout the question where appropriate. Too much markdown is overkill but some is fine. Find the balance, don't go to one extreme or the other, neither are helpful.

Comment: Well, spoiler alert: I suppose we won't know since we won't see any more of that blue fire in the next episodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## We don't know for sure.

The most popular theory going around is that his flames are merely a hotter version of Drogons' and Rhaegal's.

> Motherboard has a compelling theory that Viserion is breathing a compound called dicyanoacetylene, which would burn hotter (and bluer) than the flames he spewed as a living dragon. The hotter flames might also cause the Wall to vaporize, which is what happened — regular flames would have melted it, resulting in large quantities of meltwater. If all that's true, it means Viserion is now more dangerous than Drogon and Rhaegal, who are presumably breathing regular old fire.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Viserion's Newly Blue Flames, Explained - Cosmopolitan](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/tv/a12108352/viserion-ice-dragon-flames-explained/)</sub>

It's doubtful that his fire is any kind of the fire of a Ice Dragon.

> "Of all the queer and fabulous denizens of the Shivering Sea, however, the greatest are the ice dragons. These colossal beasts, many times larger than the dragons of Valyria, are said to be made of living ice, with eyes of pale blue crystal and vast translucent wings through which the moon and stars can be glimpsed as they wheel across the sky. Whereas common dragons (if any dragon can truly be said to be common) breathe flame, ice dragons supposedly breathe cold, a chill so terrible that it can freeze a man solid in half a heartbeat."
>
> ---
>
> <sub>A World of Ice and Fire</sub>

Viserion doesn't quite meet any of these qualifications other than blue eyes, which leads us to believe that he is still a dragon, just dead.

> Game of Thrones has never been limited by what is and isn't possible in the real world. Dragons, zombies, and shadow assassin babies all populate the world of Westeros, meaning that Viserion could breath whatever George R. R. Martin wanted Viserion to breath. However, it certainly didn't look like Viserion was breathing any kind of "ice beam" or anything type of cold breath that would imply that Viserion is an ice dragon. Viserion is still a fire-breathing Dragon, although a dead one. However, that doesn't mean his blue fire shouldn't be feared. If anything, his blue breath proves that Viserion may now be more powerful than Drogon or Rhaegal.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[How Does Viserion's Blue Fire Work? The 'Game of Thrones' Finale Just Changed The Game Entirely - Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/p/how-does-viserions-blue-fire-work-the-game-of-thrones-finale-just-changed-the-game-entirely-79452)</sub>

So, the most probable explanation is that his fire is much hotter than Drogon and Rhaegal's.

Comment: I was hoping to get a sense or reasonable explanation for a likely goof (Jon hiding and not being hurt by blue fire). But your answer made it worse :|  Well, I guess nothing can be perfect and I should move on.