# Is Jon Snow immune to dragonfire?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S08E03, "The Long Night", Daenerys's dragon Drogon blasts fire at Jon Snow to burn the wights surrounding him and he is unscathed, being half Targaryen.

But later the White Walker dragon Viserion tries to kill him with blue fire and he hides, as if he could be burnt. Is he just scared?

Comment: Because you wouldn't be afraid of a zombie dragon lunging at you? :-)

Comment: another [related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99889/73351)

Comment: I did not get the impression that he was actually caught in the dragonfire; are you positive that he was not just next to the fire?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, Jon is not immune to fire. Remember in the first season, when a wight attacks Castle Black and tries to kill Lord Commander Mormont. Jon throws a lantern at it, and burns his hand in the process.

> Jon tried to shout, but his voice was gone. Staggering to his feet, he kicked the arm away and snatched the lamp from the Old Bear's fingers. The flame flickered and almost died. "Burn!" the raven cawed. "Burn, burn, burn!"
>
> Spinning, Jon saw the drapes he'd ripped from the window. He flung the lamp into the puddled cloth with both hands. Metal crunched, glass shattered, oil spewed, and the hangings went up in a great whoosh of flame. The heat of it on his face was sweeter than any kiss Jon had ever known. "Ghost!" he shouted.
>
> The direwolf wrenched free and came to him as the wight struggled to rise, dark snakes spilling from the great wound in its belly. Jon plunged his hand into the flames, grabbed a fistful of the burning drapes, and whipped them at the dead man. Let it burn, he prayed as the cloth smothered the corpse, gods, please, please, let it burn.
> <sub>A Game of Thrones, Jon VII</sub>

Additionally, Targaryens were never meant to be immune to fire allways:

> Lastly, some fans are reading too much into the scene in GAME OF THRONES where the dragons are born -- which is to say, it was never the case that all Targaryens are immune to all fire at all times.
> [<sub>So Spake Martin - Egg and the Targaryens</sub>](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Egg_and_the_Targaryens)

Comment: Also it's not a 'normal' fire.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong maybe, we have had no indication that it is anything other than (really hot) fire. But sure, hand-wave away.

Comment: No, we can clearly see that this is not a regular fire that alive dragons breathe. Whether it has some meaning if there was any immunity involved (personally I don't think there is) is unknown.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong feel free to provide sources indicating so.

Comment: I wrote 'we can clearly see'. What source do you expect? I think you didn't get my point, but nevermind.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong I think the question is what makes you say we can clearly see? I certainly haven't seen anything to make me think dragon flame is more than a normal fire. What is it you see that makes you think otherwise?

Comment: A great dragon melted the stone walls of Harrenhall. "The towers glowed and melted like candles".

Comment: `Stone does not burn, Harren had boasted, but his castle was not made of stone alone. Wood and wool, hemp and straw, bread and salted beef and grain, all took fire. Nor were Harren's ironmen made of stone. Smoking, screaming, shrouded in flames, they ran across the yards and tumbled from the wallwalks to die upon the ground below. And even stone will crack and melt if a fire is hot enough.` Harrenhal could still be attributed to dragonfire being hot, as opposed to magical.

Comment: @JAD My bad, now I realised that I misunderstood the question. All the time I was referring to the 'blue fire' of Viserion. This is why I mentioned 'alive dragons' in my second comment. You were correct all the time. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong that explains. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Well, if that's your answer, then I feel it's your responsibility to adress the point how "Drogon blasts fire at Jon Snow to burn the wights surrounding him and he is unscathed".

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I don't know. It's not really the question. I suppose that Drogon aimed to not hit Jon with the fire.

Comment: @JAD It's pretty much the entire premise of the question. If the question was simply if Jon is fire-proof, it would have been closed as a duplicate long ago.

Answer (score 7):

## Targaryens aren't fire-proof.

From an interview with GRRM.

> Granny: Do Targaryens become immune to fire once they "bond" to their
>   dragons?
>
> George_RR_Martin: Granny, thanks for asking that. It gives me a chance
>   to clear up a common misconception. TARGARYENS ARE NOT IMMUNE TO FIRE!
>   The birth of Dany's dragons was unique, magical, wonderous, a miracle.
>   She is called The Unburnt because she walked into the flames and
>   lived. But her brother sure as hell wasn't immune to that molten gold.
>
> Revanshe: So she won't be able to do it again?
>
> George_RR_Martin: Probably not.

As to whether Daenarys is actually fire-proof there's some very interesting reading over on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/39m5lv/all_spoilers_daenerys_is_not_immune_to_fire_but/?depth=1). Some of this explains that in-universe she is not fire-proof.

> Dany hit him. “No,” she screamed, swinging the lash with all the strength that she had in her. The dragon jerked his head back. “No,” she screamed again. “NO!” The barbs raked along his snout. Drogon rose, his wings covering her in shadow. Dany swung the lash at his scaled belly, back and forth until her arm began to ache. His long serpentine neck bent like an archer’s bow. With a hisssssss, he spat black fire down at her. Dany darted underneath the flames, swinging the whip and shouting, “No, no, no. Get DOWN!” His answering roar was full of fear and fury, full of pain. His wings beat once, twice [...]
>   
>  Her skin was pink and tender, and a pale milky fluid was leaking from her cracked palms, but her burns were healing.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>A Dance With Dragons, Page 699 [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=tu2LDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA699&lpg=PA699&dq=Dany+hit+him.+%E2%80%9CNo,%E2%80%9D+she+screamed,+swinging+the+lash+with+all+the+strength+that+she+had+in+her.+The+dragon+jerked+his+head+back.+%E2%80%9CNo,%E2%80%9D+she+screamed+again.+%E2%80%9CNO!%E2%80%9D+The+barbs+raked+along+his+snout.+Drogon+rose,+his+wings+covering+her+in+shadow.+Dany+swung+the+lash+at+his+scaled+belly,+back+and+forth+until+her+arm+began+to+ache.+His+long+serpentine+neck+bent+like+an+archer%E2%80%99s+bow.+With+a+hisssssss,+he+spat+black+fire+down+at+her.+Dany+darted+underneath+the+flames,+swinging+the+whip+and+shouting,+%E2%80%9CNo,+no,+no.+Get+DOWN!%E2%80%9D+His+answering+roar+was+full+of+fear+and+fury,+full+of+pain.+His+wings+beat+once,+twice+%E2%80%A6&source=bl&ots=46AG0buaCI&sig=ACfU3U2nOyhAoMpii6zwYUugZcWt06uJRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR--f27ffhAhWXGTQIHdSDCOEQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Dany%20hit%20him.%20%E2%80%9CNo%2C%E2%80%9D%20she%20screamed%2C%20swinging%20the%20lash%20with%20all%20the%20strength%20that%20she%20had%20in%20her.%20The%20dragon%20jerked%20his%20head%20back.%20%E2%80%9CNo%2C%E2%80%9D%20she%20screamed%20again.%20%E2%80%9CNO!%E2%80%9D%20The%20barbs%20raked%20along%20his%20snout.%20Drogon%20rose%2C%20his%20wings%20covering%20her%20in%20shadow.%20Dany%20swung%20the%20lash%20at%20his%20scaled%20belly%2C%20back%20and%20forth%20until%20her%20arm%20began%20to%20ache.%20His%20long%20serpentine%20neck%20bent%20like%20an%20archer%E2%80%99s%20bow.%20With%20a%20hisssssss%2C%20he%20spat%20black%20fire%20down%20at%20her.%20Dany%20darted%20underneath%20the%20flames%2C%20swinging%20the%20whip%20and%20shouting%2C%20%E2%80%9CNo%2C%20no%2C%20no.%20Get%20DOWN!%E2%80%9D%20His%20answering%20roar%20was%20full%20of%20fear%20and%20fury%2C%20full%20of%20pain.%20His%20wings%20beat%20once%2C%20twice%20%E2%80%A6&f=false)</sub>

As shown by her inner dialogue, and the later burns healing Daenarys is clearly not completely fire-proof.

Comment: In show canon however, Dany is fire/heat proof, or at least the dragon birth was not a standalone magical feat. This is shown when she burns the Khals alive in the tent of the Dosh Khaleen (S06E04)

Comment: @BartVdW But Jon/Aegon is not fireproof, so Targaryens as a collective are not necessarily.

Comment: I agree, Jon isn't, Viserys wasn't, book Daenerys isn't always, but show Daenerys seems to be, just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that he actually got hit by the fire?

Ignoring all questions of the TV vs Book rules of whether Targaryens are *consistently* immune to fire, we saw in season 1 when Daenerys entered the fire and survived, her clothes did not. Even if she is immune to heat because of her Targaryen blood, fabric is not.

Even if Jon is in theory immune to fire like Dany, had he been hit directly by the dragon fire we would have seen some fire damage to his armour and clothing, but we didn't.